# Where is mistake in this script?

Tags: c

```
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  char *string = "<aa>RRRR|<aa>SSS|";
  char *cmp = "<aa>";
  char *p1;
  int nlen;

  main()
  {
    while ( p1 = strstr(string, "<aa>")  ) {
    nlen = 0;
    p1 = p1 + 4;
    while ( ( *p1 != '|' ) && ( *p1 != '\0') ) { p1 = p1 + 1; nlen++; };
    p1 = p1 - nlen;
    string = p1 + 1;
    char rr[200];
    strncpy(rr,p1,nlen);
    printf("%s\n", rr);
    }
  }
```

Wrong answer:

```
RRRR
SSSR
```

Comment: What's the right answer? RRRR SSS?

Comment: The variables should be local to main, with the possible exception of 'string'.  You should make that into a character array; you are not in general allowed to modify a string literal (on many systems, doing so will cause the program to terminate abnormally).  You should use an explicit return type of `int` on `main()` because C99 requires it.  You are using a C99 feature declaring `rr` where you do.  The inner loop is odd; you could use `strchr()`, of course, but why increment `p1` all the way through only to subtract the length at the end so you are back to where you started?

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a null character to terminate the string. From Wikipedia's article on [strncpy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strcpy#strncpy).

> strncpy writes exactly the given number of bytes, either only copying the start of the string if it is too long, or adding zeros to the end of the copy to fill the buffer. It was introduced into the C library to deal with fixed-length name fields in structures such as directory entries. Despite its name it is not a bounded version of strcpy, **it does not guarantee that the result is a null-terminated string**. The name of the function is misleading because strncat and snprintf are respectively bounded versions of strcat and sprintf.

Adding the null character makes your program work:

```
strncpy(rr, p1, nlen);
*(rr+nlen) = '\0';   // this line
printf("%s\n", rr);
```

I think your code could have a risk of a buffer overflow because `nlen` could in theory be greater than 200. Though this is not an issue in the program in your question because the input string is so short.

You might also want to look at [strncat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strncat) which can be used to copy a string including the null character.

> An alternative from the standard C library that will always append one null byte is to use strncat with an initially empty string as the destination.

Comment: Be very careful with `strncat()`; the length given is not the total length of the target buffer, but the space left in the target buffer after what is already there.  You can only use `strncat()` safely if you know how long the string you are concatenating to - in which case, you don't have to make `strncpy()` iterate over the initial segment of the string.  The only reason to do so is because the return value is the pointer to the start of the string passed in as the first argument - but most people most often treat the function as if it returned nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  char *string = "<aa>RRRR|<aa>SSS|"; /*make a copy below because string is const*/
  char *cmp = "<aa>";
  size_t cl = strlen(cmp); /* for shorter code below */

  char *s=strcpy(malloc(strlen(string)+1),string),*t, /* need test malloc-return */
       *last=strstr(s,cmp);
  if( !last ) return free(s),1;
  while( strstr(last+cl,cmp) )
    last=strstr(last+cl,cmp);
  for(t=strtok(s,"|");t;t=strtok(0,"|")); /* set all '|' to '\0' here */
  t=s;
  while( t<=last )
  {
    if( !strncmp(t,cmp,cl) )
      puts(t+cl);
    ++t;
  }
  return free(s),0;
}
```